# Confusion about user Authentication process in an APEX application

Tags: oracle, authentication, oracle-apex

I am trying to learn and understand Oracle APEX now a days and have a confusion about user Authentication process in an APEX application. When we create a new Authentication scheme of scheme type "Custom", there is a column called "Authentication Function Name" where we have to give the function name that will validate a username/password.

But on actual Login page, we can define another page process to do this validation.... so my question is which authentication function takes precedence? For example, I was looking in a pre-supplied sample application that the application is using a custom authentication scheme, this scheme defines "custom_auth" in "Authentication Function Name" ("custom_auth" is a stored function in the database), but in the login page of this application, there is a page process that does the actual authentication and this process calls a different function, like this:

```
wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login (
                                 P_UNAME       => v('P101_USERNAME'),
                                 P_PASSWORD    => :P101_PASSWORD,
                                 P_SESSION_ID  => v('APP_SESSION'),
                                 P_FLOW_PAGE   => :APP_ID||':1'
                               );
```

Now my question is, when a user enters his credentials and click the login button, which of the 2 functions is actually called? can somebody please help me and remove my confusion?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The whole idea is that you can plug-and-play different authentication schemes without modifying your login page - so don't change your login page's process, instead just point your application to your custom authentication scheme. wwv_flow_custom_auth_std will just call whatever authentication scheme you have set up for the application.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these functions are actually called. When user clicks login button, APEX executes page process with `wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login`, and this function calls your authentication function later. To be sure, create a table for logging and add in your function code that inserts a row in logging table. Then try to login and check table.

Answer (score 0):

begin

apex_authentication.login(p_username => :P9999_USERNAME,p_password => :P9999_PASSWORD );
end;

Comment: Consider [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code.